# How to perform a case insensitive comparison of two lists in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have two lists say

```
ListA = [Dog, Cat, Monkey]

ListB = [dog, Cat, Monkey]
```

I have used List Should Contain Sub List for comparison but it is failing for obvious reason of case change. How can I handle this with only Robot Framework Keywords.

Comment: Could you post your Robot Framework test case?

Comment: I also think that youre going to have to do some sort of Python. Only thing I can think of is make all strings the same case and then comparing them. Other than that I'm not sure :s

Comment: What about iterating the lists and comparing the values with `Should Be Equal As Strings` and setting `ignore_case=True`?

Comment: Yes this seems to be only option as of now. 
@Goralight : The original TC gets the lists from some ldap commands and files. It just gets complicated so I tried to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: @Würgspaß Is the Man! Just set `ignore_case=True` at the end of the `Should Be Equal As Strings`. I even read that documentation and didn't put 2 and 2 together :(

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and follow its advice. it's not clear why you would use "list should contain sub list" when your lists don't contain lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider you have two list
`${list1}` and `${list2}`

Use **Evaluate** which is Robot framework built in library keyword

```
${list1_lowerCase}=    Evaluate     "${List}".lower()
${list2_lowerCase}=    Evaluate     "${List2}".lower()
Lists Should Be Equal   ${list1_lowerCase}      ${list2_lowerCase}
```

Comment: That's nice! Much better than loop I've suggested.

Comment: That's actually not doing what's requested - the `Evaluate` will lower-case the string representation of `${List}`, e.g. the `${list1_lowerCase}` is actually a string with value `[u'aaa',...` - with the square brackets, the u, comma, etc. Consecutively `Lists Should Be Equal` is an overkill - `Should Be Equal As Strings` is the right one for this case.

 An approach which preserver the list type is to use list comprehension  -  `${list1_lowerCase}=    Evaluate     [el.lower() for el in $List]`, which will create a new list with all members of the original one gone through lower()

Comment: Another (one-liner) to do the check is `${equal}=     Evaluate    len($List) == len($List2) and all($List[i].lower() == $List2[i].lower() for i in range(len($List)))`  - but that's hardly readable, I wouldn't recommend it if you're not ok with python